# fql query of group feed returns "attachment unavailable" in posts of specific users

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using the graph api explorer to get the feed of a group that I am member of. I do this:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=336919223017003%2Ffeed%3Flimit%3D25

The posts in this group contain YouTube videos, and they have a "type: video", and also a link,source,name properties of the videos. most of the posts are OK.
But there are some posts that don't contain the video's properties. instead , "caption" value holds this error message:

"Attachment UnavailableThis attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you."

These posts are from specific users. I mean, posts of these users consistently contain this error message above. (which makes sense because the error suggests that I don't have permissions for these user's posts)

So How do I solve this: would it help if I was admin of this group? Do I need to ask people of the group to change some permissions in their accounts and what exactly?

Comment: Users can set their privacy settings so that other peoples' applications cannot see their data - it is likely these users have done this. They can change this setting in the "Apps others use" section in their App Settings - https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share&view